Spyder ignores breakpoints in Flask methods
For some reason, Spyder IDE ignores breakpoints inside @app.route decorators. Here is an example of the code. Please see comments in the code. The same breakpoints all work in PyCharm.
How to tell Spyder to catch breakpoints inside of @app.route?
# app.py
from flask import Flask, json
from dummy_responses import dummy_post_upload_response

app = Flask(__name__) # here breakpoint works
print('in init')
a = 5   # this variable is shown in variable explorer
print('init')

@app.route("/dummy_upload/", methods=["POST"])
def dummy_upload():
    b = 6   # this variable is not visible in explorer
    print('done')  #  here breakpoint is ignored
    return app.response_class(
        response=json.dumps(dummy_post_upload_response()),
        status=200,
        mimetype='application/json'
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=str(6010), debug=True, use_reloader=False)
    


# dummy_responses.py
from random import randint

RESPONSES = {
    'not_received': {'is_success': False, 'message': 'not received'},
    'success': {'message': 'processed', 'is_success': True},}


def ix(dct, n): 
    try:
        return list(dct)[n] 
    except IndexError:
        print('not enough keys')


def dummy_post_upload_response():
    r = randint(0, 2)  #  here breakpoint is ignored
    return RESPONSES[ix(RESPONSES, r)]

